# How to add values from different sheets, and retain the formula pointing to the sheets+cells?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, addition, worksheet

I am trying to add values from different sheets (Sheet 2 to 5) into my main sheet (Sheet 1). In Sheet 1 I want the cells to contain the right formula pointing to the different sheets (if possible).

Typically like this:

```
='Sheet2'!D5+'Sheet3'!D165
```

All my sheets have different products, but some sheets contain same products. So I want to search through them all and ADD them in my Main Sheet (Sheet 1).

```
Sub UpdateMainSheet()
' Kode for å Oppdatere Plukkeliste Alle Artikler Summert
Dim AktivtArk As String
Dim AktivtArkNavn As String
Dim K As Integer
Dim Count As Integer

'Line of code to delete old data in Main Sheet:
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:H10000").Clear

AktivtArkOverskrift = "List of Articles from Sheet 2 to 5"
'Creates Headline in Main Sheet:
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(eRow, 1) = AktivtArkOverskrift
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(eRow, 1).Font.Bold = True

'Script to check and gather data from the other sheets (Sheet 2, 3, 4 and 5):
For K = 2 To 5
    'For loop to check each line in sheet "K"
    For I = 2 To 1000
        'If function to check if the cell I in column F is empty, if so it_jumps to next row and do the same check:
        If Worksheets(K).Cells(I, 6) > 0 Then
        Count = 0
            'For loop to check if I already have a row in the Main Sheet with the article I'm checking:
            For L = 2 To 1000
                'If function to check if the articles have the same article number:
                If Worksheets(K).Cells(I, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(L, 1) Then
                    'Line of code that are supposed to ADD the values that is currently in the Main Sheet, togheter with the value in Sheet K:
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4) + Worksheets(K).Cells(L, 4)
                End If
            Next L
        End If
    Next I
Next K

End Sub
```

So what I need to fix in my code is this part (located furthest inside the For Loop):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4) + Worksheets(K).Cells(L, 4)
```

And make it create a formula in the wanted cell, that looks something like this:

```
='Sheet2'!D5+'Sheet3'!D165
```

It must be able to add another cell as well, since the Loop are running through several Sheets (Sheet 2 to 5) that may contain the same products.
I.e. I only want one line in my Main Sheet for each product.

Comment: Have you looked into Pivot Tables? You might not need any code

Comment: Hi Zac, Yes I have looked into it. The case is that I want to be able to arrange the products in two ways by using two different buttons. The first way is arranged per sheet (I got a working code for that), which allow me to see only the products asked for in each sheet (number of products to be picked). The second way is the problem I have posted here, where I want to sum the products all togheter and see how many of each products I need to pick. Also coding this makes it "unbreakable" for other users.

Comment: So you need to build a formula string with a loop?

Comment: Hi SJR, I'm not that good at Excel VBA yet, so not sure what you mean. But yes, I need a loop which allow me to scan through the 4 Sheets (2 to 5) and find the products in each Sheet (2 to 5) and sum them up in Sheet 1. I think my loop is all good, but I am struggling with the formula to ADD the values into Sheet 1, adding the new values to the values added to Sheet 1 already (adding values to same cell that a value was added to from an earlier sheet in the loop). My loop goes through Sheet 2 first, then sheet 3 and so on. Hope this clears more up, and didn't get too confusing.

Comment: Not sure if I do follow. If you adding values to a cell you can't use a formula as it will be referencing itself. What exactly is your current code not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: Let's say I have the same product in Sheet 2 and Sheet 3, and these are "Bananas" 
They have different Cell location. 
Let's say Cell D5 on Sheet 2 and D165 on Sheet 3. 
I Then want to add these two values togheter in Sheet 1.

So I want my code to Find the product "Bananas" in Sheet 2, add it to the first free cell in Sheet 1. The code runs on to Sheet 3 and finds the same product "Bananas" there, and adds this to the same cell in Sheet 1 that already have an amount of "Bananas" that was gathered from Sheet 2. [PART1 of 2]

Comment: [PART 2 of 2] And so it goes on for Sheet 4 and 5 till all "Bananas" are added to same cell in Sheet 1.

I think my loop is all good, my only problem is this part:
>Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4) + Worksheets(K).Cells(L, 4)

If it isn't possible to add a formula into the Cell in Sheet 1, it is okay if only the amount in the Cell is the addition/sum of the "Bananas" from Sheet 2 to 5.

Comment: So will the text "Bananas" be found in column A and the number is always in column D? If so, you could use COUNTIF and avoid your present loop. I'll post some code to illustrate what I mean later. Btw if you use @SJR I'm notified when you post a comment.

Comment: Sorry I mean SUMIF rather than COUNTIF.

Comment: @SJR Thanks mate. I actually found a solution on my own, in the end. See posted below as solution.
Thank you very much for your suggestions! 
If you have a solution with SUMIF, feel free to post it, as it might be more friendly to computing than my looping solution.
Otherwise have a nice weekend! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution in the end. 
It seemed I had switched the L and I in som of the looping, which resulted in the values not to be added togheter.

The following code (I did not translate to English, but can do this if someone wants/need it) solved my issue, and gave me the values from Sheet 2 to 5 sorted by product in Sheet 1:

```
Sub OppdaterePlukkelisteSummert()
'Kode for å Oppdatere Plukkeliste Alle Artikler Summert
Dim AktivtArk As String
Dim AktivtArkNavn As String
Dim K As Integer
Dim Teller As Integer
Dim value1 As Integer
Dim value2 As Integer


'Sletter Plukklisten for å oppdatere og sortere på nytt:
Worksheets(1).Range("A2:H10000").Clear


'HENTING AV DATA FRA ARKET "K":
AktivtArk = "Artikler Summert fra Alle Ark"
AktivtArkOverskrift = "Artikler Summert fra Alle Ark"
'Setter inn Overskrift som Forteller kva ark utstyret kommer fra:
eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Worksheets(1).Cells(eRow, 1) = AktivtArkOverskrift
Worksheets(1).Cells(eRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
'Sjekker hvilke/hvilket rader/utstyr som skal plukkes, og legger det inn i "Ark1":
For K = 2 To 5
    For I = 2 To 1000
        If Worksheets(K).Cells(I, 6) > 0 Then
        Teller = 0
            For L = 2 To 1000
                If Worksheets(K).Cells(I, 1) = Worksheets(1).Cells(L, 1) Then
                    value1 = Worksheets(1).Cells(L, 4)
                    value2 = Worksheets(K).Cells(I, 4)
                    Worksheets(1).Cells(L, 4) = value1 + value2
                    Worksheets(1).Cells(L, 6) = value1 + value2
                Else
                    Teller = Teller + 1
                End If
            Next L
            If Teller > 998 Then
                eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                For J = 1 To 11
                    Worksheets(1).Cells(eRow, J) = Worksheets(K).Cells(I, J)
                Next J
                Worksheets(1).Cells(eRow, 6).Font.Color = RGB(0, 150, 0)
                Worksheets(1).Cells(eRow, 7).Font.Color = RGB(0, 150, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next I
Next K

Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

I hope this can be useful for someone else :-)
All help and suggestion in the comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was going to illustrate with this simple example:

```
I = 1 'for example

For K = 2 To 5
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4).Value + _
        WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets(K).Range("A:A"), "Bananas", Worksheets(K).Range("D:D"))
Next K
```